# How to transpose a 2D vector

Tags: haskell

How to represent a 2d array integers in Haskell so that I can access any element with (i, j) in O(1) or O(logN)?

What's the difference between defining with Data.Array and Data.Vector? Which one is more practical

```
data Matrix = Vector (Vector Int)
```

If I define as the above, how to make a function that transposes this Matrix?

For instance: transposing a `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` would return `[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array` and `Vector` have similar internal representations, but the API of `Array` is designed for indexing operations (through the `Ix` class) while `Vector` has a more list-like interface and relies on fusion to combine these operations efficiently. Both allow O(1) random access.

As an aside, `Array` is available in `base` while `Vector` is defined the `vector` package, so you can use `Array` if you wish to avoid an additional dependency.

In either case, transposition can be implemented in terms of indices. It’s perhaps slightly more natural using `Array`, which can be indexed by a pair to make a 2D array that’s guaranteed to be rectangular:

```
import Data.Array (Array, (!))
import qualified Data.Array as Array

example1 :: Array (Int, Int) Char
example1 = Array.array ((0, 0), (1, 1))
  [ ((0, 0), 'a'), ((0, 1), 'b')
  , ((1, 0), 'c'), ((1, 1), 'd')
  ]

example2 :: Array (Int, Int) Int
example2 = Array.listArray ((0, 0), (2, 2))
  [ 1, 2, 3
  , 4, 5, 6
  , 7, 8, 9
  ]

transpose :: Array (Int, Int) a -> Array (Int, Int) a
transpose a = Array.array bounds
  [ ((row, col), a ! (col, row))
  | row <- [minRow .. maxRow]
  , col <- [minCol .. maxCol]
  ]
  where
    -- Note that indices need not be 0-based.
    bounds@((minRow, minCol), (maxRow, maxCol)) = Array.bounds a

transpose example1 == Array.array ((0, 0), (1, 1))
  [ ((0, 0), 'a'), ((0, 1), 'c')
  , ((1, 0), 'b'), ((1, 1), 'd')
  ]

Array.elems (transpose example2) ==
  [ 1, 4, 7
  , 2, 5, 8
  , 3, 6, 9
  ]
```

For `Vector`, you will just need to index twice:

```
import Data.Vector (Vector, (!))
import qualified Data.Vector as Vector

-- Does not handle non-square arrays, nor
-- those with an outer dimension of zero.
transpose :: Vector (Vector a) -> Vector (Vector a)
transpose v = Vector.fromList
  [ Vector.fromList
    [ v ! col ! row
    | col <- [0 .. maxCol]
    ]
  | row <- [0 .. maxRow]
  ]
  where
    maxRow = Vector.length v - 1
    maxCol = Vector.length (v ! 0) - 1
```

Note that there is no guarantee that `Vector (Vector a)` is not a “jagged” 2D array, in which the inner vectors are of different lengths, like so:

```
fromList
  [ fromList ['a', 'b']
  , fromList ['c']
  ]
```

This just means that you need to check that the input is well-formed. In addition, `Vector (Vector a)` is not contiguous in memory: it’s an array of pointers to vectors of elements, while an `Array (Int, Int) a` is a single block of memory, so `Vector` imposes a constant overhead with this representation. In case performance is a concern, you can remove this indirection by using a `Vector a` of length `rows * cols` and indexing it manually as `row * cols + col`; this is essentially what `Array` does internally via `Ix`.

Comment: For `Array`, you can avoid a lot of list allocation using `ixmap`, as in `transpose arr = ixmap (swap lo, swap hi) swap arr where swap (r,c) = (c,r); (lo, hi) = bounds arr`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with flat vectors, than sticking to `vector` package might be a good idea. But if you do need more than 1 dimension, I suggest you use a library that deals with arrays. I am the author of [`massiv`](https://github.com/lehins/massiv), as such I am a bit biased, but that is the library I'd recommend. I would definitely advise you against `array` library, despite it being wired in with ghc, its interface is very limited and a bit confusing.

For example if you'd like to transpose a 2d matrix with `massiv` you would do this:

```hs
λ> arr <- resizeM (Sz2 3 3) (1 ... 9)
λ> arr
Array D Seq (Sz (3 :. 3))
  [ [ 1, 2, 3 ]
  , [ 4, 5, 6 ]
  , [ 7, 8, 9 ]
  ]
λ> let arrUnboxed = computeAs U $ transpose arr
λ> arrUnboxed
Array U Seq (Sz (3 :. 3))
  [ [ 1, 4, 7 ]
  , [ 2, 5, 8 ]
  , [ 3, 6, 9 ]
  ]
λ> arrUnboxed ! (2 :. 1)
6
```

Note that until you call `compute` no memory allocation has happened, but you can only index it in O(1) once you compute it. Also if you apply `setComp Par arr`, this whole manipulation will be automatically parallelized for you.

There are lot more examples in the documentation if you need to get started with it.